# problem in displaying html5 page in iphone app using objective c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, html

I have an html5 page with some animations, colors using css.
when i m loading it in my application using web view, then its not showing animations, colors etc.
Please any one guide me....its urgent.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the CSS being loaded?

Comment: @sidyll: i have added it i resource folder and load only html5 page on web view. How should i add css ?